# SQL Use DISTINCT inside a CASE

Tags: sql, count, distinct

I have the following query:

```
SELECT M.TYPE, COUNT(F.CD) AS TOTAL,
COUNT(CASE WHEN F.GENDER=0 THEN F.GENDER END) AS NUM_MALE,
COUNT(CASE WHEN F.GENDER=1 THEN F.GENDER END) AS NUM_FEMALE
FROM MARC M
LEFT JOIN FUNCION F ON M.CD_FUNCION = F.CD
GROUP BY 1
```

This query returns all counts by TYPE even when a FUNCION has several lines in table MARC. But if I want only **DISTINCT** FUNCIONS how can I do it? For the first count is quite easy but how can I use DISTINCT to separate males and females?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Add some sample table data, current result, and expected result.

Comment: SELECT COUNT(DiSTINCT F.CD)... but it depends. E.g. MS Access does not support

Comment: jarlh: I want it to DISTINCT the Total result in order to remove duplicated values but I want that DISTINCT to be applied also in the following counts!

StanislavL: yes, in the first count I can use the DISTINCT just like that... the problem is with the two other counts!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `COUNT DISTINCT` with conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT M.TYPE, COUNT(DISTINCT F.CD) AS TOTAL,
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN F.GENDER = 0 THEN F.CD END) AS NUM_MALE,
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN F.GENDER = 1 THEN F.CD END) AS NUM_FEMALE
FROM MARC M LEFT JOIN
     FUNCION F
     ON M.CD_FUNCION = F.CD
GROUP BY M.TYPE;
```

Comment: You told me that e.g. MS Access does not support COUNT(DISTINCT) and suggested alternative way:).

Comment: @StanislavL, OP hasn't said this is an MS Access question.

Comment: @jarlh the provided solution does not work in common case. It depends on DB used. Gordon provided alternative way to do this and the way could be added to the answer.

Comment: @StanislavL, Gordon's query here is ANSI SQL compliant and works perfectly fine in the common case. MS Access has some limits, but that's not a reason to give Access specific answers as general, database independent answers.